# Is there any plain text colorizer for VS Code?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-code, plaintext

I´m looking for a way to colorize plain text files on Visual Studio Code.

There is a plugin that does it for Vim, called "txt.vim".

> txt.vim : Universal syntax script for all txt docs, logs and other types
>
> "This is an universal syntax script for **all text documents**, logs,
>   changelogs, readmes and all other strange and undetected filetypes.
>   The goal is to keep it very simple. **It colors numbers, operators,
>   signs, cites, brackets, delimiters, comments, TODOs, errors, debug,
>   changelog tags and basic smileys ;]** ". 
>   http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1532
>
> See a screenshot here: http://spoonman.eu/wiki/index.php?page=txt+syntax+file

Any hint on how can I get plain text colorization on VS Code?

Thanks,
Marcio

Comment: You can implement your own Colorizer. See more at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/colorizer